# Metabase DB connection to postgres :Failed to connect to database: Timed out after 5000 milliseconds

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, metabase

I have a metabase pod running in metabase namespace and postgresql db running in db namespace whereas the postgresql pod is up and running but metabase pod is failing to launch the container as its not able to connect to postgres db.

Note: This configuration was running from past 1 year and broke down recently without any changes in config etc.

error

```
01-25 07:15:17 INFO metabase.core :: Setting up and migrating Metabase DB. Please sit tight, this may take a minute...
01-25 07:15:17 INFO metabase.db :: Verifying postgres Database Connection ...
01-25 07:15:22 ERROR metabase.driver :: Failed to connect to database: Timed out after 5000 milliseconds.
java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: Unable to connect to Metabase postgres DB.
(binding [*allow-potentailly-unsafe-connections* true] (require (quote metabase.driver)) ((resolve (quote metabase.driver/can-connect-with-details?)) engine details))
01-25 07:15:22 ERROR metabase.core :: Metabase Initialization FAILED:  Assert failed: Unable to connect to Metabase postgres DB.
(binding [*allow-potentailly-unsafe-connections* true] (require (quote metabase.driver)) ((resolve (quote metabase.driver/can-connect-with-details?)) engine details))
01-25 07:15:22 INFO metabase.core :: Metabase Shutting Down ...
01-25 07:15:22 INFO metabase.core :: Metabase Shutdown COMPLETE
```

Comment: Refer to this Github [link1](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/7934) and [link2](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/1853). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @FariyaRahmat No it wasnt of any help

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused due to bad host configuration in metabase. Passing the right host resolved the issue